# Does Proxmox VE Support LVM as block storage for KVM guests?

Tags: virtualization, performance, kvm-virtualization, lvm, proxmox

Does Proxmox VE Support LVM as block storage for KVM guests to avoid the overhead of going through the filesystem layer on the host system ?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.**

Go into **Datacenter** > **Storage** > **Add** > **LVM Group**, specify an existing LVM volume group, and you are good to go.

New "disks" will be created as logical volumes on the LVM group you've specified.

Comment: and how does that work under shared LUNs? scsi-3 reservations?

Comment: I would suspect that if you wanted to use shared LUNs, then you would need a clustered file system such as OCFS2, or CLVM (clustered LVM).  I'm not sure what "scsi-3 reservations" are.

Comment: +1 Thanks Kevin, I did as you said and a new Logical Volume will be created for each VM, but in Proxmox under Defined Storage which shows list of created  Logical Volumes I see my Logical Volumes marked as RAW format. Is this a RAW image or a Logical Volume (LVM)? and does this really avoid the overhead of going through the filesystem layer on the host system ?

Comment: @Jake Once you have selected the LVM group as your target storage, the "format" option should disable itself.  And yes, using LVM means you will not deal with any file system overhead.  Although, AFAIK the file system overhead is not bad enough to be worth avoiding...

Answer (score 1):

LVM on Proxmox works on shared storage too because Proxmox uses CLVM. You simply share the same LUN to all Proxmox nodes.

CLVM and Proxmox take care, that the same LV is not used on more than one node.